# Showing ProgressBar on parsing and downloading json result

Tags: android, json, android-progressbar

In my App I am hitting a service which can have no result to n number of results(basically some barcodes). As of now I am using default circular progressbar when json is parsed and result is being saved in local DB(using sqlite). But if the json has large number of data it sometimes takes 30-45 min to parse and simultaneously saving that data in DB, which makes the interface unresponsive for that period of time and that makes user think the app has broken/hanged. For this problem I want to show a progressbar with the percentage stating how much data is parsed and saved so that user get to know the App is still working and not dead. I took help from this [link](https://www.codeofaninja.com/2011/10/android-download-file-with-progress-bar.html) but couldn't find how to achieve. Here's my Asynctask,

```
class BackGroundTasks extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {
    private String operation, itemRef;
    private ArrayList<Model_BarcodeDetail> changedBarcodeList, barcodeList;
    private ArrayList<String> changeRefList;
    String page;

    public BackGroundTasks(String operation, String itemRef, String page) {
        this.operation = operation;
        this.itemRef = itemRef;
        this.page = page;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        if (dialog == null) {
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(mActivity, null,
                    "Please wait ...", true);

        }

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
        if (!connection.HaveNetworkConnection()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
             connection.showToast(screenSize,  "No Internet Connection.");
            return null;
        }



        if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("DownloadChangeItemRef")) {
            changeRefList = DownloadChangeItemRef(params[1]);
            if (changeRefList != null && !changeRefList.isEmpty()) {
                RefList1.addAll(changeRefList);
            }


        }
        if ((changeRefList != null && changeRefList.size() >0)) {
            setUpdatedBarcodes(changedBarcodeList);
            }

        }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}




 ArrayList<String> DownloadChangeItemRef(String api_token) {
    ArrayList<String> changedRefList = null;
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(thoth_url + "/" + todaysDate
            + "?&return=json");

    String url = thoth_url + "/" + todaysDate + "?&return=json";
    String result = "";
    try {
        changedRefList = new ArrayList<String>();
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        result = httpClient.execute(postRequest, responseHandler);
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONArray jsonarray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("changes");
        if (jsonarray.length() == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject obj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
            changedRefList.add(obj.getString("ref"));
        }
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        // when there is no thoth url
        Log.i("inclient: ", e.getMessage());

        return null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // when there are no itemref

        return null;
    }
    return changedRefList;
}

 private boolean setUpdatedBarcodes(
            final ArrayList<Model_BarcodeDetail> changedBarcodeList2) {

        try {
                    BarcodeDatabase barcodeDatabase = new BarcodeDatabase(mActivity);
                    barcodeDatabase.open();
                    for (Model_BarcodeDetail model : changedBarcodeList2) {
                        barcodeDatabase.updateEntry(model, userId);
                    }

                    n++;
                    barcodeDatabase.close();
                    if (RefList1.equals(RefList)) {

                        if (dialog != null) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                         connection.showToast(screenSize,  "Barcodes updated successfully");
                    }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("Exception caught in: ", "setDownloadedBarcodes method");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }
```

Comment: Why are you not using `DownLoadManager` ? It will show progress on notification bar so user can also know that _App is still working and not dead_.

Comment: I want to show my progressabar on screen, not on notification bar.

Comment: If you'r using asynctask then in _doInBackground_ method perform your network operation which will be performed in background and dismiss dialog in _onPostExecute()_ method

Comment: @Piyush Thats what I am already doing. But now the progressbar rotates circularly however I want to show how much % of data is saved and left in the progressbar.